# SSL not working on Coldfusion 10 running on Java 8 using embedded Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, ssl, coldfusion, java-8

I updated my local CF10's jre to Java 8 and regenerated the tomcat keystore using:

`keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA`

and then pointed server.xml's HTTPS connector to that keystore.  These are the same steps I followed that allowed SSL to work when it was still Java 6, but for Java 8 I'm getting "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR" when I surf to https://localhost.  http://localhost works just fine.  My connector has port 443 defined, and like I said it worked before upgrading to Java 8.

I have all the latest hotfixes installed, so am at version: 10,0,15,292620

What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What update of CF10 are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have updated the post:  "I have all the latest hotfixes installed, so am at version: 10,0,15,292620"

Comment: Where did you run the `keytool` command? You must be sure to update the correct keystore; the one under your Java 8 folder in this case. And after updating the keystore you must restart ColdFusion.

Comment: I ran the keytool command under the Java 8 directory, updated CF's tomcat's server.xml file to point to the newly created keystore, and restarted the CF service.